# Data is not insert into database, there is no error shown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem in insert data in database; there is no error shown, but data is not inserted into the database.

**Controller Code**

```
function FormData($data){
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $data = array(
            'name'       =>  $this->input->post('name'),
            'position'   =>  $this->input->post('position'),
            'about_me'   =>  $this->input->post('about_me'),
            'contact_me' =>  $this->input->post('contact_me'),
            'email'      =>  $this->input->post('email'),
            'temp_addr'  =>  $this->input->post('temp_addr'),
            'perm_addr'  =>  $this->input->post('perm_addr'),
            'skill'      =>  $this->input->post('skill'),
            'photo'      => $this->input->post('photo'),


        );
        $this->Maboutus->form_insert($data);
        redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

**Model Code**

```
function form_insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('aboutus',$data);
}
```

**View file**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8">
             <form  action="#" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="name" class="col-md-4" >Name :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="col-md-8" placeholder="your name " required>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >Position :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="position" id="position" class="col-md-8" placeholder="your position " required>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >About Me :</lebel>
                         <input type="text" name="about_me" id="about_me" class="col-md-8" placeholder=" your name About me " required>             
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >Mobile No :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="contact_me" id="contact_me" class="col-md-8" placeholder=" your Mobile number" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >Email :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="col-md-8" placeholder=" your email " required>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >Temporary Addr :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="temp_addr" id="temp_addr" class="col-md-8" placeholder=" your Temporary Address " required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >Permanent Addr :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="perm_addr" id="perm_addr" class="col-md-8" placeholder=" your Permanent Address " required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lebel for="position" class="col-md-4" >Skill :</lebel>
                        <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" class="col-md-8" class="col-md-8" placeholder="your skill " required>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" class="col-md-8" name="photo" id="photo">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="col-md-8" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"></br></br>
                </div>
             </div>
              </form>
        </div>
```

I am new in PHP. Data is not insert in database, and it shows no error; what can I do? I tried to search but I didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: Turn error reporting on by adding this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your index.php file

Comment: i tried but nothing get

Comment: What is this `$data` here -> `function FormData($data){`? You are not passing that URL in form nor loading any view in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting to a controller/method so the post goes nowhere. In the view change the line

```
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

to this

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('controller_name/FormData'); ?>" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

In the controller change the definition of function `FormData` to this

```
function FormData(){ ...
```

You do not need to pass an argument so don't require the method to receive one.

This next bit is not relevant to your problem but a refinement to consider. You don't need to build a new array to send to the model.  Because `$_POST` is going to be populated with your fields and your table column names are exactly the same as the form's field names you can simply send `$_POST` to the model.

```
$this->Maboutus->form_insert($_POST);
```

If there was data posted that you didn't want to send to the model you would `unset` those indexes before doing the insert. It should probably be done in the model so you don't mess with the actual `$_POST` array. For example:

```
function form_insert($data)
{
    unset($data['not_to_be_inserted_key']);  //remove this item from array  
    $this->db->insert('aboutus', $data);
}
```

But that is not needed in the example you give show.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are successfully receiving the $_POST on your controller, then the problem I can see is the model, first of all you need to initialize it if you havent, you can do it with the following in your __construct

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Maboutus_model');
    }
```

Please be aware you ALWAYS need to add the "_model" after the model name

and when calling the function you do it with

```
$this->Maboutus_model->form_insert($data);
```